# htaccess add .php to everything without an extension already

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm looking around SO for duplicates, but I'm having trouble finding what I think should be a simple answer.

What are the rewrite rules to add `.php` to anything without an extension already?

examples:

www.website.com/styles.css -> www.website.com/styles.css

www.website.com/login -> www.website.com/login.php

THANKS!

Comment: In what context would you like to do this? Are these links in a file? Are they in a webpage that you're generating dynamically?

Comment: Nothing even that fancy. All the pages on my site are php scripts, I just want to use pretty URLs. I currently have a rule for every single page on my site, because I don't know the easy way: `RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]` for every single page I have... I want users to be able to type /login and get the login.php page

Comment: I would have gone with /login/ as the dir and index.php instead of login.php and remove index.php from urls.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following may suit your needs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

This will automatically add the .php extension to filenames without extensions. It may attempt to rename something.css to something.css.php, but will only do so if something.css.php exists.

Comment: how can I combine this with `CheckSpelling` to add case-insensitivity? I'm experimenting, but failing!

Comment: I don't know the answer to that - I'd recommend asking another question, to solicit more responses.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on the answer by @quinxorin you could also do the following.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php ^(.*)\.php(.*)$
RewriteRule .* %1.php?%2 [QSA]
```

This appends the remainder of the url to the result. ie `/page/1234` becomes `/page.php?1234`.

Comment: This was the only answer which worked for me AND carried over the HTTP request body with it `file_get_contents('php://input');`