# .htaccess not working on new Debian 8 setup

Tags: .htaccess, debian

So I've just set up Debian 8 on a new server, enabled a2enmod and restarted. However my links aren't working, and when I try to go in to sites-available and default I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I'm trying to change None to all, however this is still not working and is giving an error below:

```
Not Found
```

The requested URL /tos was not found on this server.

Can anyone help out on this please? 
When I change them to All instead of None, it just reloads the homepage?

Comment: There's nothing in this snippet, which prevents requests to `tos`. If the response is a "404 Not found", I would suspect it is just that, there is no tos file or directory.

Comment: however /tos.php works fine.

Comment: There's no directive enabling such a transformation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess add .php to everything without an extension already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048796/htaccess-add-php-to-everything-without-an-extension-already)

Answer (score 0):

What if you change *AllowOverride None* to *AllowOverride All* ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 20 months late, but in case someone else looks for an answer here, maybe you just need to restart the server.

something like:

```
sudo service apache2 graceful
```