# htaccess rewriting multiple conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following `.htaccess` to serve everything to `index.php`, and to prevent `.txt` static files to be displayed.

I want to add **just one additional rule**: redirect `example.com/re` to `example.com/re.php`. How to do this?

This failed, and I don't know why:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^re$ re.php       //fail: style.css won't be accessible anymore, leading to broken website
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule \.txt$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hey @basj check out this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048796/htaccess-add-php-to-everything-without-an-extension-already) - similar issue, answer might help you.

Comment: @thickguru I spent the last 30 minutes on it, but still unable to make it work. When I insert `RewriteRule ^re$ re.php [L]` anywhere, it breaks everything and make style.css broken.

Comment: RewriteCond only influences the directly following RewriteRule. So by simply inserting a different rule directly after those, you are fundamentally changing the whole thing. And the [L] flag you used according to your latest comment, is missing in the code you have shown in your question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @CBroe in a comment, **RewriteCond only influences the directly following RewriteRule**, so this is the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^re$ re.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule \.txt$ index.php [L]
```