# .htaccess code changes to remove php extension from inner pages

Tags: php, wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj2kr.jpg)I have changed my .htaccess code to remove php extension bymistaken. due to this I lost the access of my website https://ecxsolution.roundabouttech.com/. now by using [htaccess add .php to everything without an extension already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048796/htaccess-add-php-to-everything-without-an-extension-already) I can access only home page but not further pages like if i click on Contact Us page from menu. It shows page not found. what is the issue?

Comment: If you can login to admin panel try updating permalinks.

Comment: Hi, I can access all your pages from my side, there's no issue. did u try with different browser? u might have issue with browser caching

Comment: but a new promblem is there... now m not able to access the plugin part from my dashboard.

Comment: No flow-on questions please.  If you no longer need help with the first issue, delete this question and ask a new question.